# I cannot use DirectX 11 in Video Game despite being supported by Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, gaming

My PC has an `intel hd graphics 2000`for an integrated graphics processor. I checked the directX version supported by the card and it happens to be directX 11 according to the screeenshot attached below. But when i open this video game called Far Cry 3 and then head over to `Video Settings` and then `DirectX`,but i cannot seem to change that to be `DirectX11`. I also ran `dxdiag` and got the same information from the `system's tab`. So why am i unable to switch the DirectX Version?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Intel HD Graphics 2000 iGPU does not, in fact, support DirectX 11. [According to TechPowerUp](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/hd-graphics-2000.c1248), it supports DirectX Feature Level 10_1.

It is much too slow for Far Cry 3 anyway.

Comment: Yeah there is an alternative for running the game with directX 11 but it crashes and doesnt continue

Comment: Guess am gonna have to grab a discrete card then

Comment: @CodeTiger - DX11 requires hardware support, if your hardware only supports DX at the 10_1 feature level, that would explain the application crashing. There is no way to run an application that requires feature 11_0+ on hardware that doesn’t support it

Comment: In fact the HD 2000 doesn't even have Windows 10 support, let alone DX11. It was obsoleted in 2015.